# rijndael: Encrypt/decrypt the same data in C and Python

Tags: python, c, encryption, rijndael

I'm trying to figure out how to mirror encryption/decryption from an existing C function over to python. However, in my tests of encrypting with C and decrypting with python, I can't figure out some elements around the key.

These were all code samples online, so I commented things like the base64 call in Python, and at this point I'm unsure on:

**1) If I correctly determined the KEYBIT to KEY_SIZE/BLOCK_SIZE settings.**

**2) How to get from password to key in python to match the C code.**

**3) Am I  missing any core conversion steps?**

rijndael.h in C:

```
#define KEYLENGTH(keybits) ((keybits)/8)
#define RKLENGTH(keybits)  ((keybits)/8+28)
#define NROUNDS(keybits)   ((keybits)/32+6)
```

encrypting in C

```
#define KEYBITS 256

unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];

char *password = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
    key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;  

nrounds = rijndaelSetupEncrypt(rk, key, 256);

count = 0;
while (count < strlen(input)) {
    unsigned char ciphertext[16];
    unsigned char plaintext[16];
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(plaintext); i++) {
        if (count < strlen(input))
            plaintext[i] = input[count++];
        else
            plaintext[i] = 0;
    }
    rijndaelEncrypt(rk, nrounds, plaintext, ciphertext);
    if (fwrite(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext), 1, output) != 1)             
        fclose(file);
        fputs("File write error", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Decrypt in Python

```
KEY_SIZE = 32
BLOCK_SIZE = 16

def decrypt(password, filename):

    #
    # I KNOW THIS IS WRONG, BUT HOW DO I CONVERT THE PASSWD TO KEY?
    #
    key = password

    padded_key = key.ljust(KEY_SIZE, '\0')

    #ciphertext = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    ciphertext = file_get_contents(filename);

    r = rijndael(padded_key, BLOCK_SIZE)

    padded_text = ''
    for start in range(0, len(ciphertext), BLOCK_SIZE):
        padded_text += r.decrypt(ciphertext[start:start+BLOCK_SIZE])

    plaintext = padded_text.split('\x00', 1)[0]

    return plaintext
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have in the past run into real difficulties trying to do this same thing. My suggestion to you would be to rather compile the encryption / decryption piece in C, and rather figure out how to invoke a piece of C code from within Python, whether in-process (as a linked library of some kind), or out of process (as a service call)

Comment: What is the source of the rijndael function?

Comment: I have considered the external call method, but was hoping to keep it consolidated. @Keith The sample code is from somewhere on the web, I do not remember where I got it unfortunately. If you are talking about the actual rijndael.c and rijndael.py files, I could paste them, but they are very long and I believe pretty standard files.

Comment: Could you not implement AES using PyCrypto? If you choose 128-bit blocks and 256-bit keys, Rijndael is the same thing as AES256.

Comment: @Fmstrat This is a VERY BAD question and exactly what the Stackoverflow community doesn't want. The code has been taken from http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm and Fmstart doesn't want to say where he found it. Fmstart  removed all the headers so you can't copy-paste and compile it. And he managed to break the code!!! The python code is here: https://github.com/jjh42/countdr/blob/master/pdfminer/rijndael.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example C code just copies 32 bytes from the `password` string into the key. If the key is less than 32 bytes, it padds on the right with zeroes.
Translated into python, this would be:

```
key = password[:32]+b'\x00'*(32-len(password))
```

Which actually produces the same result as

```
password.ljust(32, '\0')
```

You should note however that this method of generating keys is considerd [*extremely unsafe*](http://bityard.blogspot.nl/2012/08/symmetric-crypto-with-pycrypto-part-3.html). If the attacker suspects that the key consists of ASCII characters padded with 0 bytes, the keyspace (amount of possible keys) is reduced considerably. If the key is made out of random bytes, there are 256^32 = 1.15e77 keys. If the key e.g. begins with 8 ASCII characters followed by zeroes, there are only (127-32)^8 =  6.63e15 possible keys. And since there are [dictionaries](http://www.skullsecurity.org/wiki/index.php/Passwords) out there with often-used passwords, the attacker probably wouldn't have to exhaust this reduced keyspace; he would try the relatively small dictionaries first.

Consider using a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) or another proper [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to convert the passphrase into a key.

Try using the [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) toolkit. It implements [Rijndael/AES and other ciphers](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#crypto-cipher-encryption-algorithms).

Comment: Neither a cryptographic hash function nor a KDF creates any entropy - if you use an 8 character password as input to SHA256 (or any other hash) there are still only (127-32)^8 possible keys.  A KDF adds salt to make dictionary attacks across multiple passwords less effective, but since the salt is known, it adds no entropy and no difficulty to the search for a single password.

Comment: @Dave I presume this is additional information for Ben as it doesn't invalidate any of the information in the answer?

Comment: @Dave: Using the entropy function ported from https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/, the entropy of a SHA256 hashed string 'password' is much greater than that of the same string right-padded to 32 bytes with zeroes...

Comment: @RolandSmith: No, a program that performs statistical tests on a set of data does not measure entropy.  What you care about is the number of inputs an attacker needs to try before guessing the password.  That number is the same (on average half the number of possibilities) for the raw zero-padded password or a hash of the password or a salted hash of the password.

Comment: The WPA2 password converter used for Wi-Fi network keys (http://jorisvr.nl/wpapsk.html) uses many iterations of a hash function to convert a password into a hex key.  But if your WPA2 password is 4 digits, you can brute force guess it in 5000 tries on average (10,000 tries if you're unlucky), regardless of how complex the 64 hex digit string appears to a statistics-measuring function.

Comment: @Dave: the entropy calculation that I used is the definition of Shannon entropy.

Comment: @RolandSmith: The calculation you use is obviously not the definition of Shannon entropy, because it is not properly estimating the correlation between symbols.  If it were properly calculating entropy, it would discover the extremely high correlation between the first n bits of a hashed password and the remaining bits of the hash value.

Comment: @owlstead: it invalidates the implication that the hash of an 8 character password is safer than zero padding the same password.  If the password/phrase is long enough (contains enough entropy) to prevent brute-force guessing, the one-way property (preimage resistance) of the hash function will prevent the password from being derived analytically from the key.  But if the password is short enough to be guessed, hashing it makes it no safer.

Comment: @Dave: Please look up the definition of Shannon entropy (e.g. in the Wikipedia article I linked to) and show me where it 'estimates the correlation between synbols'?

Comment: @RolandSmith: I can't give you a course on information theory in SO comments.  But it's in the very first sentence of the Wikipedia article: "In information theory, entropy is a measure of the uncertainty associated with a random variable."  If random variables are correlated, uncertainty of the second given the first (conditional probability) is reduced.  If they are perfectly correlated, uncertainty is zero.

Comment: @RolandSmith suggesting something like PBKDF2 is a good thing, but reasoning that it would increase the entropy is certainly not and I have to agree with Dave here.

Comment: I've removed the entropy stuff.